Can I have some help identifying/locating this show I’ve been trying to find?
I remember this show that I watched in the mid 2000’s that I believe I watched on Netflix. Unfortunately I’m having trouble with recollecting the entire premise, but I do remember that it consisted of a group of characters that all had some sort of elemental companion or beast. The only identifying scene that I remember from the show was that one of the characters in the group had tragically lost his companion (I believe it was linked to flame or fire in some way) and while on an adventure, had located a new creature in a cavern or cave that he managed to convince to become his new companion. If I remember correctly the object of this specific adventure or mission was to located some sort of artifact or perhaps something related to magic. I also remember this new companion to have a decent temperament and that it took quite a bit of convincing for the male character to be able to tame or become friends with it. I think the creature had a gollum esc design, however, I can’t say for certain if that’s correct. I’m pretty sure the show had an animation style something akin to The Legend of Korra, but I’m hoping that’s not just my brain filling in the missing memories with something I am currently familiar with.
Apologies for the lack of description but it’s all I can remember about this show from when I was younger. I’ve attempted to search literally everywhere I could but there seems to be no trace of it. I’m hoping this wasn’t just the product of an overactive imagination as a kid and would be deeply grateful if anyone would be able to find it. I remember having some pretty good memories of watching it as a kid and would really like to be able to watch it again.

Please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/tips-for-asking-story-identification-questions to find more questions to help prompt you to [edit] more details in.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this a series or a movie (OVA)?

So this specifically looked like hand-drawn animation? Do you remember if the group were kids? Adults? Racial/gender makeup? Hair color?

I remember it was a series and the group were in their teens or were young adults

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MonsSeries might be a handy place to look, although I haven't found anything yet.
